# CSS display block on hover

Tags: html, css

I've following HTML, the div `.info` has `display:none` by default, I want to change that to `display:block` on hover. I'm trying following CSS but the `:hover` does not work.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="items">
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">
            <div clas="info">

            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#items .item a .info{
    display: none;
}

#items .item a .info:hover{
    display: block;
}
```

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/qcDtF/

Thanks.

Comment: how can you hover it, if its not displayed at all in the first place?

Comment: interesting. how hover event can occur if the element is hidden?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot hover over something that is not displayed. You could use [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/opacity) or [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/visibility) instead. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qcDtF/2/).

```
.info {
   opacity: 0;
}

.info:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Alternatively, if you really want to use `display:none`, then give `#items`, `.item`, or your outer `a` a set width and height, and place the `:hover` on that element. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLCu5/1/). For example:

```
#items{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}


.info{
    display: none;
}


#items:hover .info {
     display: block;  
}
```

If you want the correct `width` and `height`, you can use javascript/jQuery to get the width/height of a visible `.info`, hide `.info`, and then set the height/width of `#items` to those values gotten from `.info`.

Answer (score 2):

you have not display the content in info its not possible to hover the hidden

you can do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/swamimayank/uLCu5/)

```
<div id="items">
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">sd
            <div class="info">
                asdf
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#items .item a .info{
    display: none;
}

#items .item a:hover  .info{
    display: block;
}
```

you can not do this by hover but you can change the opacity on hover so it feels like it will hide and show as the user @jeff gortmaker says

aslo

**if you have  jquery as option then you can do this like**

```
$('.info').hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(1,1);
},function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(1,0);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swamimayank/P8Ems/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `visibility` instead of `display`:

```
#items .item .info {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#items .item:hover .info {
    visibility: visible;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qcDtF/1/